# What is a Seaman's book, and can it really replace a passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork, seamans-book

What is a "Seaman's book", and can it really replace a passport for some or all immigration purposes?  Even Wikipedia the all-knowing does not seem to know, although it contains many tantalizing references.

[UK immigration enforcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_immigration_enforcement):

> Seaman deserters may not have a passport but rather hold a Seaman's Book, (a national identity document issued to professional seamen that contains a record of their rank and service career).

[Visa policy of Hong Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Hong_Kong):

> Possession of one of the following documents is sufficient to demonstrate [right to abode] ...
>
> 6. Hong Kong Seaman's Identity Book

Comment: I looked into this a bit more and am increasingly confused about the fine gradations between a Seaman's Card, a Seaman's Book, a Seafarer's Identity Document, Ordinary Seaman's Certificate, Merchant Mariner's Document, Merchant Mariner Credential etc.  Here's hoping a salty sailor comes along to sort out the mess...

Comment: I'm primarily interested in what the deal is right now, but I'm secondarily interested in everything travel-related :)

Comment: Wikipedia knows about the [1958 convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafarers%27_Identity_Documents_Convention,_1958) and the [2003 convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafarers%27_Identity_Documents_Convention_(Revised),_2003).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The 'Seaman's Book' provides a travel document that can be used instead of a passport *in some cases*.  In order to be used as a passport, the situation must be appropriate (i.e., joining or leaving a vessel) and the book itself must contain all of the information that a passport would normally contain.

But the big selling point of having a Seaman's Book, comes when it is presented by a person who would ordinarily require a visa to enter the country.  If the seaman can show that he is joining or leaving a vessel then the border official can waive the visa requirement.

Example: A Nigerian national with a Seaman's Book is joining a vessel currently anchored in Marseille and due to sail somewhere else.  He can present his Nigerian passport along with his Seaman's Book and enter the zone without having to get a Schengen visa.

This will work in every country that is a signatory to the  [International Labour Organization (ILO) Convention 108](http://www.ilo.org/global/standards/subjects-covered-by-international-labour-standards/seafarers/lang--en/index.htm) (and in limited circumstances [ILO No. 185](http://www.ilo.org/dyn/normlex/en/f?p=NORMLEXPUB:12100:0::NO::P12100_ILO_CODE:C185)).  The linked site contains all the provisions and details.

So they are a great thing to have, but hard to get.

Comment: Can a civilian get one?

Comment: @JoErNanO, yes. see http://www.maritimeskills.org/careers/merchant_navy/mn_quals.htm for how to get started

Comment: @JoErNanO given the ILO angle, I suspect that *only* civilians can get them.

Comment: GayotFow, if my edit is incorrect, please advise and/or roll back.  Thanks.

Comment: In practice, an invitation letter/printed-email from employer is also needed along with seaman book and passport to enter one country