# Greece Schengen Visa for Seaman

Tags: schengen-visas

I joined a Belgian flag vessel docked in Greece, had a 2 week Schengen visa single entry, now that said visa is expired long time now do I need to go back and get another visa to continue my stay? What are my options to be able to stay in Greece and, the vessel is still in Greece and no plan of leaving anytime soon.

Comment: Can you make the question more clear please? where are you? nationality? etc.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53090/what-is-a-seamans-book-and-can-it-really-replace-a-passport

Comment: Are you leaving with the vessel? What type of visa did you receive?