# Do passengers and crew on cargo ships require visas?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, freighter-travel

If I am on a cargo ship that docks in a foreign country, like Brazil for example, but I do not come ashore and do not intend to come ashore will customs still board and demand passports and visas for all passengers and crew?

I am assuming the ship is refueling or is only stopping temporarily at the port.

Comment: Are you crew? or a paying passenger?

Comment: And what nationality?

Comment: This is for a paying passenger. My nationality does not matter. I am asking whether the customs/immigration people will come aboard demand documents on me from the captain, even if I do not disembark.

Comment: Crew are generally covered by their crew documents, in place of a passport, and often have different rules about whether they require a visa. These rules would not apply to passengers on a freighter.  Passengers on cruise ships often enjoy relaxed documentation requirements, but these generally apply only to cruise ships, and sometimes only if the cruise begins and ends in the same port.

Comment: As vessel enters a country's national waters, and in order to dock, port authorities are provided lists of both crew and passengers. The authorities have the right to board the vessel, and to ask for documents that identify both crew and passengers (as well as search the vessel).

Comment: As I understand it, the question is about passengers. I suggest deleting all references to "crew" because they have their own rules that can be very different from passengers.

Comment: Yes, you are a foreigner entering the country.  The fact that you arrive by sea vs air is not really a consideration for immigration.  However, there is quite a bit more to this depending on where the ship berths, existing arrangements with local authorities, etc.  The vessel operator is best equipped to answer these questions.

Answer (score 11):

As a rule (but not an ironclad one), **no**, you will not require a visa if you stay on board. Immigration takes place only on disembarkation.

Procedures do vary from country to country though, and some countries [such as Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_migration_zone) do require being in possession of a valid visa in order to enter their territorial waters, even in transit.

Comment: Though see @Dorothy's comment above: while immigration controls *generally* take place when you leave the vessel, there can be exceptions.  Certainly, if a passenger is wanted by the authorities of that country, there will be little hope of evading capture by electing to remain aboard while the ship calls at port.

Comment: @phoog Clarified.  And yes, you're still in the country's jurisdiction, even if you haven't gone through immigration.  See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18561/1893

Comment: Per your own question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53090/what-is-a-seamans-book-and-can-it-really-replace-a-passport

Answer (score 8):

For the crew of a ship, the [seaman's book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafarers%27_Identity_Documents_Convention,_1958) can replace visa in certain circumstances. It requires nations which have ratified the relevant conventions, and it applies to merchant crew who travel **with** their ship to a port or **towards** their ship waiting in a foreign port.

Comment: @pnuts, the title of the question mentions both passengers and crew. This is a Q&A site with an archive, so I answered for other readers.