# EU 90-day rule on a cruise ship

Tags: schengen

I live in the UK and in April departing from Newcastle for a 15-day cruise. I am just questioning how it would count me being in the EU if I don't get off the cruise.

Ideally I want to save as many of my 90 days for travelling this summer, so if there is a way I can not count some / all of my cruise days I will.

The itinerary is Newcastle to Canary Islands and Portugal and back.

Comment: What is the itinerary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens with my Schengen days when I board/alight a cruise in the UK without stamping my passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171605/what-happens-with-my-schengen-days-when-i-board-alight-a-cruise-in-the-uk-withou)

Comment: Hello, The itinerary is Newcastle to Canary Islands and Portugal and back.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica But only from peaple who require a visa to enter the Schengen Area anyway. This is not the case for the OP.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thanks. It is the case for the OP if they're a UK citizen. We might presume that, but it's a guess. I'll amend my comment and re-post it.

Comment: Be aware that sometimes, some cruise lines require you to either have a passport that allows you visa-free entry into cruise port stops, or to have a visa enabling you to go ashore, whether you intend to do so or not. If you have a Schengen visa (or don't need one) and don't go ashore, no days will be counted against your Schengen time limit...

Comment: ...On the other hand, if you require a visa to disembark and the cruise line requires you to have a visa and you don't have one, the cruise line may not let you board the ship for the cruse. Check the Terms and Conditions applicable to your cruise. I'd ask the cruse line directly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Article 11 (3)(d) of the Schengen Border Code states that the passports of passengers of a cruise ship who are not subject to border checks will not be stamped.

Such checks will only be done when leaving the ship while in port **unless** they believe that there is no need to carry out such checks.

Otherwise your are only noted as being on board in a list.

This would mean that only the days when you leave the ship **and** they actually perform a Article 8 border check (where your passport would be stamped) count for the 90 days.

Only the days with an entry/exit stamp in your passport are checked during later visits. (Article 8 (3)(iii))

---

> **Article 11 - Stamping of the travel documents**
> (1) The travel documents of third-country nationals shall be systematically stamped on entry and exit. ...
> ...
> (3) No entry or exit stamp shall be affixed:
> ...
>
> > (d) to the travel documents of crew and passengers of **cruise ships** who are not subject to border checks in accordance with point 3.2.3 of Annex VI;

---

> **Annex VI**
> 3.2.3. If the itinerary of a cruise ship comprises both ports situated in the territory of the Member States and ports situated in third countries, by way of derogation from Article 8, border checks shall be carried out as follows:
>
> > (a) where the cruise ship comes from a port situated in a third country and calls for the first time at a port situated in the territory of a Member State, crew and passengers shall be subject to entry checks on the basis of the nominal lists of crew and passengers, as referred to in point 3.1.2.
> > **Passengers going ashore shall be subject to entry checks in accordance with Article 8 *unless*** an assessment of the risks related to internal security and illegal immigration **shows that there is no need to carry out such checks**;
> >
> > (b) [similar to (a)]
> >
> > (c) where the cruise ship comes from a port situated in a Member State and calls at such a port, **passengers going ashore** shall be subject to entry checks in accordance with Article 8 if an assessment of the risks related to internal security and illegal immigration so requires;
>
> ---
>
> **Article 8 Border checks on persons**
> ...
> 3. On entry and exit, third-country nationals shall be subject to thorough checks as follows:
> ...
>
> > (iii) **examination of the entry and exit stamps on the travel document** of the third-country national concerned, in order to verify, by comparing the dates of entry and exit, that the person has not already exceeded the maximum duration of authorised stay in the territory of the Member States;