# What visa do I need to enter Italy?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, italy, ships, sicily

I am an Indian national. I need to join a survey vessel in Sicily. I want to know what kind of visa do I need to enter sicily, Italy to join the ship. I need to go there in February, 2019.

Comment: Are you eligible for a Seaman’s Book? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53090/what-is-a-seamans-book-and-can-it-really-replace-a-passport

Comment: http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/mumbai/transit.html if you want to do it yourself. Check with your ship though; they may already be contracted with a visa service that can help you through the process.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.